# Python script not writing on files after cx_Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am working on a script I intend to freeze with cx_Freeze. I'm using Python 3.6 and cx_Freeze 5.1.1.

The problem I am facing at the moment is that my Python script -- perfectly working as `.py` --, once frozen with cx_Freeze, does read the content of a `text.txt` file but seems unable to write on it.

I have written a simplified version of what I'm trying to do and the problem is still there.

This is my `main.py`:

```
from tkinter import *

def writing():
    word = str(word_field.get())
    ft = open('text.txt', 'w')
    ft.write(word)
    ft.close()

def from_file():
    ft = open('text.txt', 'r')
    string = ''
    for line in ft:
        line = line.strip()
        string = string+line
    ft.close()

    root2 = Tk()
    result = Label(root2, text=string)
    result.grid(row=1, column=1)
    root2.mainloop()

 root = Tk()
 root.title('My window')
 word_field = Entry(root)
 btn_1 = Button(root, text='Read', command=from_file)
 btn_2 = Button(root, text='Write', command=writing)

 word_field.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
 btn_1.grid(row=2, column=1)
 btn_2.grid(row=2, column=2)

 root.mainloop()
```

And this is the `setup.py` that I used for cx_Freeze

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os.path

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

setup(
    name = "Prova",
    version = "1.0.0",
    options = {"build_exe": {
            'packages': ["tkinter"],
            'include_files' : [os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'), \
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'), 'text.txt'],
            'include_msvcr': True,
            }},
        executables = [Executable("main.py", base="Win32GUI")]
        )
```

Any idea about why it does behave like this?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I just tried your script and it works as I would expect it to.  I compiled and it worked then too. What Is going wrong for you?

Comment: Hi Simon, the problem I face is that, using the frozen script, I can read the content of the file but not write on it. If you say that it works for you, I guess the problem may be somewhere else.

As I was now curious I tried to install it on another machine and it doesn't work either. So the problem, probably, is not in the way the script is written but in the freezing process. Any suggestion?

Comment: Ping next time you want to talk to someone (@Simon) I would have replied earlier knowing you had responded (I only got this message because I just happened to be looking here).  Yes when I press read it reads a line, when I write it writes the line I entered.  I need more info that that.  What was the OS version, error tracebacks (this is the other machine you mentioned).  Are you sure there are no errors when running from CLI?

Comment: It might be worth a shot but honestly I've never heard of anything like this happening before.

Comment: Hi @Simon , first info (I am using Python 3.6, Cx_Freeze 5.1.1, Win7 64bit). When I tested the script before freezing it I kept looking on the terminal and there was no error or traceback, it just works. After I freeze it, clicking on button 1 it reads the content of the file but if I write in the Entry field and click button 2 it seems to have no effect, the file is simply unchanged. I even tried to install to freeze it on a different pc and it doesn't work either. I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: Did the other pc return an error when run through CMD?

Comment: Also are you sure you are running it from CMD?  By that I mean open cmd, enter cd followed by the location of your exe and then entering the name in the next line.

Comment: @Simon this is the most curious thing. Nor on one PC neither on the other one any error is shown in the cmd window. It just does not write on 'text.txt'.
(Of course we are talking of the executable I get after installing the file I get with 'python setup.py bdist_msi').

I just tried with pyinstaller and the exe in the folder it creates would seem to work, but this is not an installable version, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update on this question: After a good number of different configurations (and I even tried to use PyInstaller instead of cx_Freeze), it comes out that the problem wasn't in the script or in the freezing process itself but in the fact that, as the executable file requires to write on a file this is in conflict with the privileges given to the executable.

This means that the executable cannot write on the file, the program stops but no error message is generated (not even running it in the cmd window).
I will create a new dedicated question and I will then post here the link to it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread died 2 years ago but since I had the same problem and I thought it was difficult to find a solution I'll still write here something

The issue for me was the folder where the .exe was. It was in a random folder so it did not have permission to write on files.
I solved this by moving to \Appdata\Roaming the folder with the build. After doing this the program runs.